# How does Stun (stun extradamage) and battlefury stack?

Tags: dota-2

Imagine the following situation. Faceless Void having his stun skilled which stuns at a percentage rate and does extra damage.
If he now buys a Battlefury and hits a direct target and stuns it, do the other targets who gets cleaved as well take some extra damage? If yes how many % ? 30% as the cleave says or is it the full extra damage from my skill ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if you look at [Faceless Void's Wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Faceless_Void), it says that the bash damage is *magical*.

Secondly, even if it were Slardar's bash, which is physical damage, Battle Fury would not cleave that damage. The only proc that adds to cleave damage is a critical hit. Your regular damage will be cleaved, but your bash damage will not.

You can read more about cleave [here](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Cleave).

Comment: You forgot Kunkka's Tidebringer which should cleave in the area of the Battle Fury if i am not mistaken.